# Entity Framework 4 -- possible to call a SSDL function from within another SSDL function's commandtext?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Is it possible to call a SSDL function from within another SSDL function's CommandText?  For example, let's say I have the following SSDL function defined in my edmx file:

```
<Function Name="blah" IsComposable="false">
  <CommandText>
    ...blah related stuff...
  </CommandText>
  <Parameter Name="blah_param" Type="int" />
</Function>
```

Can I define a second SSDL function that calls "blah"?  For example:

```
<Function Name="blah2" IsComposable="false">
  <CommandText>
    ...
    blah(3);
    ...
  </CommandText>
  <Parameter Name="blah2_param" Type="int" />
</Function>
```

"blah" and "blah2" do **NOT** exist as stored procedures on the database and are fully defined in the SSDL of the edmx.  I tried qualifying the call with a handful of different things (appending the SSDL namespace to the function name -- BlahModel.Store.blah(3), using "execute procedure" and "call" SQL keywords, etc).

It appears that once it hits the CommandText tag, everything is sent over to the database and no parsing/resolving of the inner CommandText is done.  Does anyone have any insight into whether this is possible or not?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible. [CommandText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283136.aspx) should contain a valid SQL/Transact-SQL/PL/SQL expression only.